# Does xml layout for different screen orientations or witdths have to have identical structure

Tags: android, android-layout

For instance, can I have an extra TextView in layout-land xml(which not exists in layout xml) and what will happen if I setText on it and user is in portrait orientation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting a layout to a specific orientation then the extra view that exists in that orientation view would dissapear from the content view that you are setting. Hence when you try to find after the orientation has changed and the new layout lacks this views then the view it will return null because it does not exist in the given layout.

Comment: So basically I would have to test if that View exists every time I referencing it in the code, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `TextView` in landscape which doesn't exist in xml then if the orientation changes your `onCreate()` will be called after calling `ondestroy()` i.e. your `Activity` will be recreated. Hence if you have initialized your `TextView` inside your `onCreate()` then it should work just fine. You can also save the data of your activity and show it even when the user changes orientation by using `onSaveInstanceState(state)`.